# CentOS 6.7 configure: error: dlopen not found

Tags: linux, centos, libreoffice, owncloud

I'm trying to configure LibreOffice On-Line WebSocket server before installing but the following error is thrown:
configure: error: dlopen not found

Full output:

```
[root@SBX-EXT-001-002 loolwsd]# ./configure --enable-silent-rules --with-lokit-path=${MASTER}/include
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for setcap... /usr/sbin/setcap
checking whether to run tests against a LibreOffice... no
checking for library containing dlopen... no
configure: error: dlopen not found
```

I have the 3 dependencies mentioned installed.

```
[root@SBX-EXT-001-002 loolwsd]# ldconfig -p | grep "libpng"
        libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0
        libpng12.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so
        libpng.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpng.so.3
[root@SBX-EXT-001-002 loolwsd]# ls /opt/poco
bin  include  lib
```

Any point in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It's in glibc, in particular you need to have glibc-devel installed...
Also you need to install the build dependencies:

```
sudo yum-builddep libreoffice
```

- On Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice

  - With modern releases, use autogen to select a newer gstreamer,
  - or install the old package with: sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
- On OpenSUSE 11.4+: sudo zypper si -d libreoffice
- On Fedora 22+ & derivatives: sudo dnf builddep libreoffice
- On Fedora 21+ & derivatives: sudo yum-builddep libreoffice

Comment: glibc-devel is installed.

Comment: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnLinux#Build_dependencies

Comment: If sudo yum-builddep libreoffice wouldn't help you should look here(http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xsoft/libreoffice.html) which packages are required for build in LFS